# Copying 2x2 array contents into 4x6 array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, copy

I'm new to Java programming and my assignment was to copy the content of 2x2 two dimensional array into the middle 4x6 two-dimensional array. I did it anyway but it doesn't print out the way I wanted and I dont know why. Can someone help me identify the problem in my source program. Thanks in advance

```
public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
         int[][] a = {{11,12},{21,22}};
         int[][] b = new int[4][6];
    
         System.out.print("a[][] = \n");
         output(a);   
         System.out.print("\nb[][] = \n");
         copy(a,b);


    }
    
    static void output(int[][] x) {
    
        for(int i=0; i<x.length;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<x[i].length;j++) {
                System.out.printf(" %2d ", x[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    
    static void  copy(int[][] source, int[][] destination) {
        
        for(int i=0;i<source.length;i++) {
            destination[i]= new int[source.length];
            System.arraycopy(source[i], 0, destination[i+1], 2, destination[i].length);

            }
        output(destination);
        
    }
    
}
```

The result should be

```
a[][]
 11 12
 21 22
b[][]
  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0 11 12  0  0
  0  0 21 22  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

but I got

```
a[][] = 
 11  12 
 21  22 

b[][] = 
  0   0 
  0   0 
  0   0  21  22   0   0 
  0   0   0   0   0   0
```

instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing several things wrong:

- replacing the destination row with an empty array of source size.
- using the destination length instead of the source length

Here is how it should look.

```
 static void copy(int[][] source, int[][] destination) {

     for (int i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
         System.arraycopy(source[i], 0, destination[i + 1], 2,
                 source[i].length);
     }
     output(destination);
 }
```

I have included a more general solution as follows:

Not all arrays will lend themselves to this kind of copy.  I return a boolean if the copy was successful or not. Here are some guidelines.

- Copying to center implies the same number of unfilled rows above and below, or the same number of unfilled columns to the left or right. This can be determined by subtracting the smallest dimension from the largest and seeing if the remainder when divided by two equals zero.  If so, the copy should succeed and true is returned.   Else, an informational message is  printed and false is returned.
- The starting location of each row or column is determined by subtracting the shorter dimension from the longer one and dividing by two.
- The loop iterates over the source array while the `System.arraycopy` does the work of copying to the destination, incrementing the destination row index.

```
int[][] arr = { { 11, 12}, { 21,22}};
int[][] dest = new int[4][6];
if (copyToCenter(arr, dest)) {
        for (int[] rows : dest) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rows));
        }
}
```

prints

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 11, 12, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 21, 22, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

The copy method.

```
static boolean copyToCenter(int[][] source, int[][] destination) {
     if ((destination.length - source.length) % 2 != 0
             || (destination[0].length - source[0].length) % 2 != 0) {
         System.out
                 .println("Arrays do not lend themselves to required copy");
         return false;
     }
     
     int firstCol = (destination[0].length - source[0].length) / 2;
     int destRow = (destination.length - source.length) / 2;
     for (int[] sourceRow : source) {
             System.arraycopy(sourceRow, 0, destination[destRow++],
                     firstCol, source[0].length);
     }
     return true;
}
```